# Why are hydraulic pumps mounted on engines 2 and 3 in BAe 146?

Tags: aircraft-design, engine, electrical-system, hydraulic-system, bae-146

The [BAe 146](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aerospace_146) has 4 engines:

- engine no. 1 and 4 generate electricity
- engine no. 2 and 3 generate hydraulic pressure

Why was this setup chosen?

Comment: Answer should be posted as answers, not as comments

Comment: I think you question may be too vague: BAe 146 has two electrical buses and two hydraulic systems, so I'm not surprised they've chosen two engines for the electrical and two for the hydraulics. Why they select that engines or why not having an extra generator/hydraulic pumps is a design choice difficult to say...